Case when expression giving incorrect output
Looking to get solution on below table. I have ID, Status, Case Function and required Output column.
My query is to show if cancelled status is against ID and if another row for same ID have NULL or changed Then 2 else 1.
Thanks in advance



id
status
case_function
required_output




1001
null
1
1


1001
changed
1
1


1002
cancelled
2
2


1002
changed
1
2



I am trying to say "case when CaseFunction = 1 and CaseFunction = 2 then 2 else 1 end" as Required Output.
This is what I tried:
SELECT 
  ID, Status, CaseFunction, 
  CASE WHEN CaseFunction= '1' and CaseFunction = '2' 
    THEN 2 
    ELSE 1 END AS 'Required Output' 
FROM #dat

However, when I write above expression I get required output as 1 instead of 2 when I have status as cancelled.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Please show us your attempt

Will there always be only 2 records per ID? Is there a unique identifier field? Will [Case Function] always be 1 or 2?

Please [edit] any clarifications into your question

@June7 Every ID may have 1 or more records.

@DaleK This is what i tried ** SELECT ID , Status , CaseFunction , CASE WHEN CaseFunction= '1' and CaseFunction = '2' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS 'Requied Output' FROM #data **

If your data is always in this form, meaning the only possible values of case_function are 1 and 2, you can simply fetch the windowed MAX(case_function) per id:
SELECT
  id,
  status,
  case_function,
  MAX(case_function) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS required_output
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY id;

See this sample fiddle

Jonas Metzler,
Thats working for me. Thats exactly i wanted. Thank you !
